# Perl: Uploading a file from a web page

Tags: perl, file, upload

I am trying to upload a file from a web page without using:

```
my $query = CGI->new;
my $filename = $query->param("File");
my $upload_filehandle = $query->upload("File");
```

My form has several input fields and only one of them is a file name.  So when I parse the form I parse all of the input fields in one pass.  This means that I have the filename withough using `my $filename = $query->param("File");` but, as far as I can tell, this means I can't use `my $upload_filehandle = $query->upload("File");` to do the actual uploading.

Any advice is appreciated.

Regards.

Answer (score 0):

How are you parsing the input fields?  More importantly why are you using `CGI` and reimplementing some of its functionality?

This should still work:

```
my %args              = how_you_are_parsing_the_url();
my $query             = CGI->new;               #this parses the url as well
my $upload_filehandle = $query->upload("File"); #assuming the input is named File
```

Comment: I am parsing the fields of the whole form at once rather than input field by input field.  I am using:

[code]
my $FormData;
if ($ENV{'REQUEST_METHOD'} eq "POST")
{
   read(STDIN, $FormData, $ENV{'CONTENT_LENGTH'});
}

# Get the name and value for each form input:
my @pairs = split(/&/, $FormData);

...and so on.
[/code]

Comment: I tried:

    my $upload_filehandle = $query->upload("File");

with no luck.

Comment: @Schemer is your input that holds the file named `File`?

Comment: I decided to parse my form entirely using the cgi query.  However $upload_filehand is always empty even when $filename is read.  Here is the code snippet:  
my $query = CGI->new;  
my $url = $query->param("urlInput");  
my $file = $query->param("fileInput");  
my $upload_filehandle = $query->upload("fileInput");  
my $text = $query->param("textInput");  
my $k = $query->param("kInput");